# MVVM positioning of a dialog wpf

Tags: wpf, mvvm, dialog

I use a service to manage dialogs, which works nicely and decouples the visualization details from my view models.

My code (below) can easily set the dialog window owner to the Main Window, but what I would *really* like to do is position it next to the graphical item (ie, button, whatever) that called it.

Has anyone got an MVVM solution to this?

Cheers,
Berryl

```
    // helper to create and prep windows in WPF
    private Window _createWindow(
        string key, object dataContext, bool setOwnerToCurrentMainWindow, 
        EventHandler<UICompletedEventArgs> completedProc, bool isModal)
    {
        var win = _registrationService.CreateRegisteredType<Window>(key);
        win.DataContext = dataContext;

        ...

        if (setOwnerToCurrentMainWindow)
            win.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;

        ...

        return win;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Then whats stopping you? As far as I know, taking help of `Attached Behavior` is perfectly allowed in the MVVM scenario.

If you dont want to try this using attached behavior **totally** ... then

The existing graphical item's coordinate values `Top-Left` and `Size` can be `OneWayToSource` bound to your parent View's data context (lets say `ParentVM`).

**If not because `ActualSize` is ReadOnly so bind it via an `Attached Behavior` (again perfectly allowed in MVVM).**

So the `ParentVM` can hold Top, Lef, Bottom, Right coordinates of the original graphical item. They can be sent across to your Window creation call via the `dataContext` (which is something I guess you can send) where we can bind that to the child Window's `Top` and `Left`.

Do criticise if there is something a miss in my reply. :)

Comment: Attached Behaviors still don't come naturally to me - can you scratch one out in code? Cheers